# get Activemq Dequeued messages statistic over time

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to monitor activemq Dequeued messages overtime and save them in Zenoss monitoring system.

I can see the Dequeued number in the control panel of activemq, however if I restart activemq, those numbers are reset.

What's the best way of capturing statistics?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way it's designed, there's no way to recover that information after a restart.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use a 3rd party monitoring tool (Nagios, Cacti, etc) to dump AMQ stats into (some even have AMQ plugins).  These tools are designed for long term monitoring/charting/alerting of system resources and are pretty easy to hook up to AMQ...